# Expose Docker API over TCP on Alpine Linux using OpenRC

Tags: docker, alpine

I have searched everywhere but just can't seem to find the answer. I need to expose the Docker API over TCP on Alpine Linux using OpenRC.

I know how to do it on Ubuntu with systemd:
create `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/startup_options.conf` and add:

```
[Service]  
ExecStart=  
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376
```

Hopefully I've given enough information for someone to understand what I am trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working! after probing around the file system found the docker conf.d script (`/etc/conf.d/docker`) modified this line:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:port -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

Answered in case anyone runs into the same problem I did :)